# Sens de "escogru"

Tags: sens, néologismes

Bonjour,

Je suis tombé sur le mot *escogru* dans *Féerie pour une autre fois I* :

> Il nous insulte l'**escogru** ! qu'on le découpe ! tranche ! pende à
> verdir ! (p. 67)
>
> Oh mais l'**escogru** nous persifle ! flambard ! cocu ! imbécile ! (p. 74)

Il n'y a pas de note dans l'édition de la Pléiade. J'ai trouvé sur [ce site](https://duclos.tripod.com/Dictiona.htm), qu'il s'agit d'un néologisme formé à partir de *escogriffe*.

Je me demande, tout de même, quel est l'effet apporté par le suffixe *gru* ? Y a-t-il quelque chose à voir avec le mot [*grue*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/grue) ?

Comment: Si on parle d'incongru qui me parait une bonne piste d'explication, d'après l'étymologie le mot vient d'*incongruus*, *congruo* issu du verbe *gruo* apparenté à *ruo*, "s'élancer vers" https://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/incongru https://gaffiot.fr/#congruo

Comment: @guillaume31 Merci pour votre commentaire !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Il semble que le seul mot français en *-gru* soit *incongru*.

Ses trois définitions du [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/incongru) s'appliquent bien à cet *escogru* :-)

> Qui ne convient pas; inattendu et surprenant.
> Qui manque de savoir-vivre.
> Contraire aux normes de la grammaire, aux bienséances du langage.

Answer (score 0):

- Définition

  **ESCOGRU n.m.**
  Néologisme à partir de *escogriffe*.

  > *Il nous insulte l'escogru ! qu'on le découpe ! tranche !' F1, 67.*

  Source: [Dictionnaire Céline](https://duclos.tripod.com/Dictiona.htm) (lien trouvé dans la question).

La définition [d'escrogriffe](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/escogriffe) est apparentée à *escro[c]* dans le sens *voleur* (prendre sans demander). L'origine n'est pas certaine, mais on suppose qu'il s'agit d'une composition d'*escroc* et de *griffe*.

Donc la syllabe "-gru" viendrait du mot "griffe" et non du mot "grue". L'exemple sur Wiktionary laisse à penser qu'il s'agit du mot griffe dans un sens figuré. *Les impôts, la griffe de l'État.*

Il est certain que le mot défini d'une forme d'escroc, voyou, individu malfaisant.